# When to use "is" vs. "are"

Tags: grammaticality

Joining us in the studio is Secretary of State John Smith and Attorney General Bill Jones. 
or
Joining us in the studio are Secretary of State John Smith and Attorney General Bill Jones.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 2):

"Secretary of State John Smith and Attorney General Bill Jones" are more than one individual, so *are* is correct.